# Customer Rating options for different attribute sets or categories

Tags: extensions, review

I want to display different customer rating options assigned to different categories or attribute sets.

For example, in category A or attribute set A, we have a price rating. But, in category B or attribute B, we only have a quality rating.

Is this possible or, is there an extension for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm looking to do the same,

Cat A
Value
Quality
Fit

Cat B
Enjoyment
Value
Comfort
Stay

I've looked at a few modules that have advanced reviews, but none appear to allow 'rating sets' as such.

Any info or direction to a solution you had would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards

Steve